# App doesn't run when exporting react & react-router to a stand alone html file with webpack

Tags: javascript, cordova, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to export my react `SPA` to a single `html` with `js` so I can install it into a `phonegap` application.

I have my production "ready" webpack.config however when I export the files everything is bundled up and appears to be ok. But the application stops when it gets to the `Provider`.

**Entry Point - src/client/js/Entry.js**

This is the entry point

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { Router, browserHistory, Route, IndexRoute  } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux'

import Root from './core/Provider'
import configureStore from './core/Store'

const store = configureStore;
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

console.info('Entry') //OUTPUTS correctly
render(
    <Root store={store} history={history} />,
    document.getElementById('app')
)
```

I can confirm that `<div id="app"></div>` in there on page load.

**Provider.js**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'

import App from './App';
//###### Routes #######
import Splash from '../components/pages/Splash';

export default class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    console.info('Provider'); //Provider Correct
    const { store, history } = this.props;
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
          <Router history={history}>
            <Route path="/" component={App}>
              <IndexRoute component={Splash}/>

            </Route>
          </Router>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import * as ActionCreator from '../actions/ActionCreator';

import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(nextValue) {
        browserHistory.push(`/${nextValue}`)
    }

    render() {
        console.info('App'); //No console log, does not render
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
    // Injected by React Router
    children: PropTypes.node
}

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    return {
        errorMessage: state.errorMessage,
        inputValue: ownProps.location.pathname.substring(1)
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        SexAction: bindActionCreators(ActionCreator, dispatch)
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

**What I expect when the application is running correctly**

[image: What I expect when the application is running correctly]

**What I am seeing with the stand alone app**

[image: What I am seeing with the stand alone app]

**Store.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import rootReducer from './Reducers'
import defaultStates from '../states/statesDefault'

const configureStore = function (preloadedState) {
    const Store = createStore(
        rootReducer,
        preloadedState,
        compose(
            applyMiddleware(thunk, createLogger())
        )
    )

    if (module.hot) {
        // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
        module.hot.accept('./Reducers', () => {
            const nextRootReducer = require('../../js/Entry').default;
            Store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer)
        })
    }

    return Store;
};

export default configureStore(defaultStates);
```

**Webpack.prod.js**

```
.......   
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: [
    path.join(__dirname, 'src/client/js/Entry')
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/'),
    filename: '[name]-[hash].min.js',
    publicPath: './'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'public/index.tpl.html',
      inject: 'body',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name]-[hash].min.css'),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        warnings: false,
        screw_ie8: true
      }
    }),
    new StatsPlugin('webpack.stats.json', {
      source: false,
      modules: false
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    }),
    ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,presets[]=stage-0'],
        include: __dirname
      }
     ......
};
```

**Everything is being exported correctly**

[image: Output of dist folder]

**[Edit] - Node.js & Express**

I realised I have missed out a key bit of information no doubt. I am using node and express. I start my app with `npm start`

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
const config = require('./webpack.config.js');

const isDeveloping = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const port = isDeveloping ? 6004 : process.env.PORT;
const app = express();


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));

const compiler = webpack(config);
const middleware = webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  contentBase: 'public',
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    hash: false,
    timings: true,
    chunks: false,
    chunkModules: false,
    modules: false
  }
});

app.use(middleware);
app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler));
app.get('*', function response(req, res) {
  res.write(middleware.fileSystem.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html')));
  res.end();
});

app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', function onStart(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.info('==>  Listening on port %s. Open up http://0.0.0.0:%s/ in your browser.', port, port);
});
```

Comment: This is pretty broad. What's one specific thing you're expecting the application to do that it's not doing? Show that code, and if we can figure out why that's not working, it might reveal why the whole application is not working.

Comment: I concur. However I must say I am unsure how else to pose the problem. I believe that essentially `render(
 <Root store={store} history={history} />,
 document.getElementById('app')
)` Is some how not working. I can confirm its being run though. Thanks for helping to trouble shoot though, you ask questions and I get a little closer.

Comment: I have updated the question and narrowed down the problem. Now I can identiy where the application is not `rendering`

Comment: That `console.info('Entry') //OUTPUTS correctly` line would cause a syntax error; if that is removed, does it still not work?

Comment: Sorry that is a typeo in the SO version :) But good spot

Comment: Also, those state change console messages may be of interest; you should inspect the before/after store state. The store is obviously running if those messages are popping up. Maybe this is just an issue with responding to your initial route.

Comment: Yes I thought the same, `state, history` both exec as expected. However it also occurred to me, I am using `browserHistory` I wonder how impact this would have as I am using `http://localhost:6004/anotherpage` for example. So not hash tags but `/`'s for the paths. Without node running how can my `react-router` understand these?

Comment: That should be fine; `browserHistory` enables real URLs in the browser via the HTML 5 history API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). Hashes aren't necessary.

Comment: `syncHistoryWithStore` may be important too; maybe what that's returning isn't usable as a history object. You could try passing `browserHistory` directly into the router.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123978/discussion-between-jamie-hutber-and-jacob).

Comment: I actually wasn't worried about it moving between states with the history api. It is more a fear that, the browser will try to go to that url `/something/something` but there is no file there, no end point. So how does it know what to do with it.

Comment: If you use `react-router` links, it will change the URL via the history API, and your router will respond to URL changes. It won't go to the server unless you initially load/reload the page on that URL.

Comment: Argh thank you @Jacob Indeed this makes sense. I am going to the root so ye, it should work.

Comment: cordova apps must be aware of CSP (Content Security Policy). another thing that might help you is to plug an usb clable on the device, deploy the apk there and then use chrome://inspect for better debug.

Comment: I'm nowhere near phonegap yet, just trying to make the thing run on chrome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We discovered in chat that the issue is incompatibility (at least in Chrome) of the HTML 5 history API with `file://` urls. The `browserHistory` provided by `react-router` is a wrapper around this. However, for `file://` URLs, you can use `hashHistory` instead:

```
import { Router, hashHistory, Route, IndexRoute  } from 'react-router';

// ...

render(
  <Root store={store} history={hashHistory} />,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Comment: Have to wait 21h :)